# Isometric Tile Generation

Tags: java, loops, isometric

So my issue is, usually when I generate my maps I'd use the following:

```
for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
       tiles.add(new Tile(x, y));
    }
}
```

You can get the just of that. 
Anyway I need to pretty much have pragmatic way of doing this in an isometric / 45 degree rotation.

Say the first loop you'd add new Tile(width / 2, 0).

Next loop you'd add new Tile((width / 2) - 1, 0), and new Tile((width / 2) + 1, 0).

I've experimented with a few differing ways to do this, but haven't had much success.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to keep the representation the way you're used to, and just display the tiles in an isometric way, that is, rotated by 45 degrees? So that the top-most tile is actually at (width-1, 0), the two in the next row are at (width-2, 0) and (width-1, 1) (assuming counter-clockwise rotation)?

Comment: @Thomas Although that might be an easier way, the issue with it is that the tiles only keep track of their X & Y positions, and are stored in a list. so it's difficult to calculate their offsets when rendering.

Comment: Oh, I see. For some reason I was assuming that you would use a two-dimensional array for a grid, even though your code clearly indicates a list. My bad. I've updated my answer below to remove that assumption - I think the general idea I laid out still holds.

Comment: I've updated my original answer quite a bit. I've added a paragraph showing that with my suggested encoding of (x,y)-coordinates, it is in fact quite easy to calculate a tile's rendering offsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it seems like you're trying to represent the tiles for an isometric game, e.g.:

[image]

For this, your `Tile`s store the (x,y) information of their location with the following layout:

```
y \ x | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6
------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
   0  |   |   |   | A |   |   |
------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
   1  |   |   | B |   | C |   |
------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
   2  |   | D |   | E |   | F |
------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
      |   |   |   |   |   |   |
```

and so on.

However, I would suggest to decouple the internal representation of your tile grid from the way it is displayed. Just because you want isometric graphics doesn't necessarily mean that you have to store your `Tile`s' (x,y)-positions in a diamond shape as well.

Instead, try the following layout for each of your tiles:

```
y \ x | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 
------+---+---+---+---
   0  | A | C | F | 
------+---+---+---+---
   1  | B | E |   | 
------+---+---+---+---
   2  | D |   |   | 
------+---+---+---+---
      |   |   |   |
```

That is, tile `A` is created as `new Tile(0,0)`, tile `B` as `new Tile(0,1)`, etc.

With this representation you'll get the advantage that adjacent tiles in your isometric display will only differ by `1` in either the x- or the y-direction. This should make the initialization step of your `tiles` list much easier.

To map these coordinates to the isometric display positions, remember that tile `A` at location `(0,0)` is at the top of the diamond. You can then compute the display positions of all other tiles relative to that one:

- The difference in the x-coordinate translates to moving right and down
- The difference in the y-coordinate translates to moving left and down

So let's assume your display renders `A` at the pixel coordinates `(px, py)`, and every tile is rendered with a width of `pWidth` and a height of `pHeight`.

The horizontal offset for `tile` can then be computed by walking right `tile.x` times and walking left `tile.y` times. Because of the isometric view, you only offset by half of the width in every step.

```
int pxTile = (tile.x - tile.y) * pWidth / 2 + px;
```

The vertical offset is computed similarly. While `tile.x` and `tile.y` cancel each other out in the horizontal directorion (since left and right are opposite of each other), they both contribute to moving down in the vertical direction.

```
int pyTile = (tile.x + tile.y) * pHeight / 2 + py;
```

Unless your game does scrolling/zooming, you can compute the pixel coordinates of every `Tile` right in the constructor, because they only depend on the values of (x,y) and the constants `width`, `px`, `py`, `pWidth`, and `pHeight`.

Comment: Thank you, finally got it sorted :)